# i can't edit my question

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

i have a problem since beginning of this week. if someone ever answer or comment to my question, i cant edit or retag my own question...that options became lost...i can only edit when nobody reply or comment the question

What is wrong wth it?  i didnt have this problem before

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237993/i-can%27t-edit-my-question/) by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-06-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-24**:
If you are sure this is not browser related (ie: try another one to make sure / clear cache), then you might want to report this at [ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues).

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-06-27**:
I have the same problem

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-27**:
I've just reported this: [ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org#137](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues/137).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should be fixed. According to the developer:

> Fixed, there was an error in determining which edit links to hide.

Please let us know at [ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org#137](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues/137) if editing works for you again.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-06-27**:
thanks for reporting, its okay now...i wrote there a comment too